# File is encrypted or is not a database sqlite3 VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, encryption, sqlite, corruption

My client/server application is written on VB.NET and it uses sqlite3 (*.db3) database. Everything was working fine with the old .db3 database unless I had to delete it and make a new one. I am using SQLite Maestro to create the database, import tables and data and that's it, but for some reason server won't read the database anymore saying that "file is encrypted or it's not a database file". Alright, what just happened? This is an old project from 2012, I remember all I did was just create the database in Maestro, add the tables and the data and it was all working like a charm. Now doesn't work doing exactly the same thing! I though that they changed something and Maestro is creating db's differently now, so I tried to use older version, but it's not possible to use older version of the program. I noticed that whenever I create a fresh database and attempt to use it with the server and every time it shows the error message that the file is encrypted or it's not a database then the database is corrupted. I can't open it in SQLite Maestro anymore. What should I do ?

Don't know if this matters, but here's the code that reads the database:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source={0};version=3;", ReadDatabasePath())

Private Shared connection_ As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Connection() As DbConnection
        Get
            Return connection_
        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: First, SQLIte is serverless so the issue is limited to just that UI tool and your code.  Next, you tagged this with encryption, so did you create an encrypted DB?  You should make sure you are using compatible versions of the SQLite connector and UI tool.  Finally, as your code demonstrates there is very very little involved in creating a connection, so why create a helper to encapsulate one line of code?  A "global" connection string is all you really read

Comment: The point is that declaring and reusing a single connection is bad, wrong even. So is this a web based thing?  There is very little to go on here without the code that actually results in the error.  Triple check that the DB file path and filename are absolutely correct

Comment: I found out that the problem was because I used very old SQLite extension in the server (from 2012) and when build the new database with the current version it doesn't work cause of mismatch of sqlite version. Fixed it by reinstalling the latest sqlite on the server. Thanks.